# Turn off screen on boot

Tags: applications, screen

**How can I have my device automatically turn off its screen after booting?**

- booting as in having turned off the device, finished charging and turning it back on
- turn off screen as in the function after single-pressing power button

At night, I turn off my device to charge it overnight. In the morning, I turn it on. Since the boot process takes a long time, I usually leave it on the counter for it to   ***s l o w l y***   boot up. During this time, I get ready for my morning (which takes longer than for the device to boot). Taking the device with me to manually turn off the screen once it is finished booting is not good enough for me.

Short of building my own app that runs itself once on boot or having it turn off the screen after *n* seconds of inactivity, how can I have my device automatically turn off its screen after booting?

The device in question is not rooted, but answers requiring root privileges are acceptable
(I plan on rooting the device... eventually...)

Comment: The phone has a feature  that turn the screen off after an amount of time when the phone is not being used, just set it to, say, 30 seconds and the screen will turn off. Correct me if that is not what you are asking for.

Comment: Oe do you mean turning off the screen WHILE the phone is being booted?

Comment: @esQmo_ That is what I am trying to avoid as I usually read ebooks where I do not touch the screen before the *n* seconds is up (I suppose I could change the inactivity time manually after each boot)

Comment: @esQmo_ I do not mind when the screen is off, just a reasonably time during/after it is being booted

Comment: @esQmo_ At the current state, the screen is on for ~5 minutes after it has finished booting (which is a waste of battery charge)

Answer (score 0):

For this, I suggest you use an app called [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) with this app, - among other things - you can set it that when you are not using any app, the screen should timeout after x amount of time, but while you are using an app, it will time out at a different amount if time.

1. download [Tasker.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (it is a paid app, but it has so much to it that it's worth the money)
2. Open the app and press on the '+' symbol on the bottom right of the screen. And press 'application'
3. Now select the apps in which you want the display to stay on for a long time. For example your ebooks app, or any other app. Select as many apps as you want for this action.
4. Press on the back button on your phone. Now it will ask you what you want to happen when you open those apps.
5. Press on 'new tasks'
6. Type a name for this task something like 'screen timeout 5 min'
7. In this new window, press on the plus symbol, and in the search bar type 'display timeout'
8. Press 'display timeout', and now under where it  says 'mins' choose the amount of time you want the screen to stay on for, while using the apps.
9. Press on the back button twice, and you should be brought back to the main page.
10. Long press on 'screen timeout 5 min' (or whatever you named this task) and press on 'add exit task' -> 'new task'
11. Give the new task a name something like 'screen timeout x seconds.'
12. Here, do the same as steps 7 and 8 just when setting the time, set it to the amount of time you want the screen to stay on while you're not using the selected apps.
13. Now, go back all the way to the main screen of Tasker and press on the check mark symbol on the top right. (If you don't see a check mark symbol, then don't worry about it, just doing this step)
14. Test to see that all is working by going to your home screen and see how long it takes for the screen to go to 'sleep' it should be the amount of time selected in step 12, then go into the selected apps and see how long the screen stays on.

Comment: 1) Tasker is a good approach. 2) It has a 7-day-trial available at its home page. 3) OP didn't ask for display timeout on an app – so the correct context would rather be *Event › Power › Battery Full* or *Event › System › Device Boot* and the Task not "display timeout" but rather *Display › Stay On* (set to false; assuming the device still being connected to power is what's keeping the screen on) or *Display › Turn On* (false again; if present at all, as this is device specific).